# Pure CSS Solution - Square Elements?

Tags: css, layout, width, aspect-ratio

If I have a `<div>` with a relative width (such as *width: 50%*), is there a simple way to make it have the same width as it does height without resorting to JavaScript?

Comment: do you mean dynamically, meaning if the width increased then the height would match it automatically?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, I do; updated to reflect that.

Comment: that sounds like you want to use logic in css, which to my knowledge is not possible at this time. remember, css's job is not to handle logic (at lease not of this caliber) but merely layouts and display. stuff like this (mathematic calculations) is exactly what javascript is meant to do.

Comment: JavaScript is more a means of dynamic interaction, not a crutch to achieve a certain layout. This logic is really quite simple compared to current CSS capabilities. I'm surprised that there aren't methods to size an element using an aspect ratio.

Comment: It's not a crutch when the current tools can't do what you need them to do. You being surprised doesn't change the fact that it can't be done in CSS alone at this time.

Comment: @TreyKeown i guess a can relate. back in the day when i first started getting the hang of html/css/js i couldn't for the life of me understand why there wasn't a feature built into css or js to allow the rotation html elements, it seemed like an obvious feature (probably because i've done so in actionscript/flash).

Comment: @TreyKeown take it form me, i've had to do a lot of black magic hacks to achieve stuff that seems almost elementary simply because it's a limitation the tools currently have.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is actually possible to achieve it with this neat trick i found at
[this blog](https://pagecrafter.com/maintain-aspect-ratio-for-html-element-using-only-css-in-a-responsive-design/)

```
#square {
   width: 100%;
   height: 0;
   padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This would work, and indeed it does answer my original question. However, my requirements have slightly changed, and I need to be able to size the element by having a certain percentage for the height, and then set the width accordingly to make the element square. This solution doesn't quite seem to work for that. Though, perhaps a kluge would be to use transform: rotate(90deg); for the element, and transform: rotate(270deg); for the content within.

Answer (score 12):

### No, and Yes (Kinda)

Okay, so the short answer is "no," not possible. The long answer is, "yes," given certain constraints and concessions (i.e. extra html markup, and limitations on what can be done).

Given this CSS:

```
.square {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px;
    display: inline-block; /* could be float */
    overflow: auto; /* UPDATE: if content may overflow square */
}
.sq-setter-w {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.sq-setter-h {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.sq-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

With this HTML:

```
<div class="square" style="width: 200px">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.gif&text=50x50" class="sq-setter-w"/>
    <div class="sq-content">Here is content</div>
</div>
<div class="square" style="height: 100px">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.gif&text=50x50" class="sq-setter-h"/>
    <div class="sq-content">Here is content</div>
</div>
<div class="extrawrapper">
<div class="square" style="width: 200px">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.gif&text=50x50" class="sq-setter-w"/>
    <div class="sq-content">Here is content</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="extrawrapper">
<div class="square" style="height: 100px">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.gif&text=50x50" class="sq-setter-h"/>
    <div class="sq-content">Here is content</div>
</div>
</div>
```

### You can get it to do [what this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/UWERB/4/).

The keys are:

1. The image used needs to be a square image, as it is driving the proportional sizing (the `img` element is the only element that can do such proportional work, as it can base its size off the proportion of the image itself).
2. You have to know if you are going to set the `width` or the `height` so that you can set the image class correctly to size it. *Optionally*, set the `width` or `height` on the `img` itself, then you don't need to worry about setting a class to the `100%` value. My demo was assuming that you set the size on the wrapper div (my `.square` class).
3. To get the `div` to collapse around the `img` which is driving the proportional sizing you need to set `display: inline-block` or a `float` on the `div` (as noted in the css above).
4. Because of #3, if you want that `div` to act more "block-like" you need to give them an extra wrapper `div` like the third and fourth ones show.

*Obviously, there is a lot of extra mark-up involved in this solution.* So in many ways it is better to say "just use javascript," but I did want to prove that it could be done (at least in some cases) purely with HTML and CSS.

### Update: To Show Flexible Sizing Possibility

[**See this fiddle for percentages driving the size**](http://jsfiddle.net/UWERB/12/), with this html example (`width` set to `30%`):

```
<div class="square" style="width: 30%">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000/fff.gif&text=50x50" class="sq-setter-w"/>
    <div class="sq-content">Here is content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: [This seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693956/how-can-i-create-a-perfectly-square-div-where-height-is-equal-to-viewport) to be working for me...

Comment: Until the "update" part, I wasted my time trying to figure out how "not using fixed size" in the element to set it on the wrapping elements is of any use. It's like wishing not to grow and putting yourself in one of those boxes used to grow watermelon square. 
I'll take a look at the second fiddle, but so far you wasted my time.
Your first example (did I say "useless" already?) with content does this http://jsfiddle.net/8x91z9a2/  Can you explain me what is the difference between all this extra code and setting width and height with one div and two lines of css?

Comment: @sergio: The challenge was to explicitly set the div to be _square_, using _only_ HTML/CSS, and only having _one_ value (either height or width) driving the size of the square, without necessarily even knowing ahead of time what that value might be (either dynamically generated or being a percentage). So form (square) is fixed with unknown values. That is the "use" of it. The content overflow in your example is a possible by-product of a designer not handling the content amount or the overflow, which [I would recommend `overflow:auto` on the square class](http://jsfiddle.net/8x91z9a2/2/).

Comment: Making a container to stop working as a container (i.e. the content will overflow it) is the same that just setting a gradient single-color background with size set to "contain", or just using an image.
There's no point on keeping the container as container if it's not gonna contain anything.

Answer (score 2):

I needed to achieve something similar today and had the same idea with the image. I wanted to check other possibilities and google led me here.

...you don't really need an image `src`. you can simply use a `hash` if you want a square.
It saves a http request.

If you want to get different aspect ratio you should use a `src` though. If you want to have a ratio of 16:9 the image should be `16px` wide and `9px` high (go as small as possible)

---

### Comparing both techniques (see other answers in this thread)

#### `img` vs. `padding-bottom`

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/V8Y5c/) to show how much more compatible the `img` version is (can easily handle `px`value too (an interval will resize the "square" each second)

If you use percentage values both techniques can achieve the same result but the padding version does not need the extra markup (`<img src="#"/>`)

---

### Conclusion:

Depending on the implementation each technique has it's pros and contras.

---

#### HTML

```
<div class="floater">
    <div class="square square_noImg">
        <div class="inner">Hey blue you look totally squared</div>
    </div>
    <div class="square square_img">
        <img src="#"/>
        <div class="inner">Hey red you seem off</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.floater {
    font-size: 0;
}
.square {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 5px; 
}
.square_noImg {
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background: red;
}
.square_img {    
    background: blue;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    right: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    background: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 10px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A native JS approach in response to @Dave comment on @praveen-kumar answer:

```
var squareElement = function(el) {
    el.style.height = el.offsetWidth + 'px';
}
```

and use it anywhere

```
squareElement(document.querySelector('your-selector'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with CSS alone. Using jQuery you can achieve this by doing

```
var chld = $('.child').width();
$('.child').css({'height':chld+'px'});
```

Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/4Jnfq/

---

A CSS only solution can be found **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359039/607874)** on the last "Resize with content" update.
Although it applies for circles, you can remove the `border-radius: 50%` to make it work for squares.

Comment: To note jQuery isn't the only answer... Javascript in general can do it. I'm not a fan on JS libraries personally.

Comment: This can be done in CSS alone, as you check in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359039/607874) (see "Resize with content" update). It is an answer for responsive circles but the same applies for squares.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Been a long time buddy. Why digging up old ones?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I agree that's an old one, but nevertheless its always good to improve solutions for other fellows with the same problem.

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos Agreed... Go ahead and edit my answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Not with relative units like `%`, because they would be calculated relative to a container element. But it's possible to make an element square if you use units like `px` or `em` to set both dimensions.