# Make a square with a height 100%

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a square with height 100% of the screen only in css. I know that I can do this with JS by calculating the height and applying this to width and height, but I am looking for only css solution.

I have found the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021146/1090562) but it looks like it makes width 100%. When I tried to make height 100% with

```
.square{
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

nothing shows up (take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Nxjs/27/)). Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Is that a typo? Having `height` twice, the second being `0`?

Comment: If you mean 100% of the viewport height, you can just use `100vh` for both the `width` and `height` of your div, like in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/9Nxjs/20/

Comment: @putvande yes, it is a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: @KingKing thanks. Amit already posted such answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/c43QG/

```
.square{
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that not all browsers support `viewport-units`: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

1. You set first time height to 100%, on next line to 0. Why?
2. you have to add height: 100% to html too

   ```
   <style>
   html, body{
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
   }

   .square{
       height: 100%;
       padding-right: 100%;
       background: red;
   }
   </style>
   <div class="square"></div>
   ```

   http://jsfiddle.net/9Nxjs/2/

Comment: Why did this get two up-votes? This doesn't solve anything...or what am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this would do http://jsfiddle.net/r8732/

```
<div class="dummy_class">
  I am height : 100%
</div>

   html, body{
    height:100%;
}

.dummy_class{
    height:100%;
    background-color : red;
}
```

Add height:100% to your html

Comment: and does this look like a square to you? Have you noticed that it makes all display red?