# Child div not filling parent

Tags: html, css

I know this title is probably about the most common on SO, but I seem to have a very specific problem that I can't find documented.

I have a `div` that I want to be exactly square, so I followed the CSS advice in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18021146/889604).  I also want a child `div` to fill this space, so I've followed all the standard guidelines of having a `clear:both` `div` in a wrapper, etc, but my child div is *still* not filling its parent.  The problem is the `height: 0` of the parent div - is there a solution to this but still maintaining the exact square (preferably pure CSS, I'm aware there are JS solutions).  Example of this is at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hy80ksj/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can give the inner box an `absolute` position and set it to conform to the edges of the containing box:

```
.box div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hy80ksj/1/)

Not sure if it's any better to what you proposed, maybe if you wanted content in the box?

Comment: Thanks! This seems like a pretty robust approach.  I'll do some experimenting and see which result seems better :)

Comment: As you say, this does work better when I want more content. The simplistic way I came up with breaks when there's more content, because of the effect of padding on the content in the child div

Answer (score 2):

If you're not too worried about [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) then using vh, vw, or vmin would be a good alternative.  Since height would actually be set you could easily set the child element to fill the parent.

CSS:

```
.parent {
  width: 50vmin;
  height: 50vmin;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGaveG).  I like vmax, but it's  not as well supported as vmin, vh, and vw.

Answer (score 1):

This padding trick for responsive boxes work with `absolute` positioning.

[css-padding-trick-responsive-intrinsic-ratios](http://www.fredparke.com/blog/css-padding-trick-responsive-intrinsic-ratios)

So use `absolute` positioning for inner div.

```
.box {
 ...
  position: relative;
}

.box div {
  ...
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this different to the [very good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31025326/889604) posted below?

Comment: didnt noticed. anyway `right: 0; bottom: 0;` is not required as mentioned. height:100% will work

Answer (score 0):

Adding `padding-bottom: 100%` to the child `div` does fill the space and seems to be a fix; the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hy80ksj/2/) reflects this

Comment: I won't accept this answer yet in case there are better alternatives or this is shown to be a bad method!

Comment: while you linked the answer in your question you should not write answer yourself.

Comment: Why does your .box div have 0 height? That's the real problem.

Comment: @Perplexor that's how the perfect square is maintained

Comment: @BhojendraNepal it is perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: NO. The linked answer and your answer is same. So, delete it.

Comment: No, you get a square div by setting it's height to the same value as it's width. Why complicate things with 0 height and a lot of padding?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal sorry, I'm confused, *which* linked answer?

Comment: @Perplexor because he wants the square to be dynamic, the only alternative I can think of would be to use js.

Comment: @Perplexor - that works if you have a fixed size square, not a responsive square :)

Comment: Then maybe using viewport units would be better? `height: 38vw; width: 38vw;`

Comment: @ChrisW You linked the answer in your question.

Comment: @Perplexor that's a very good solution so long as support for IE 9  and below is not an issue.

Comment: @Perplexor ah, I hadn't realised viewport units could be used like this!

Comment: @BhojendraNepal as far as I can see, there's nothing in the answer I linked to that explains the answer to the question I asked - can you explain what you mean? :)